# Can I set a layout from a class? (without an Activity)

Tags: android, class, layout, drawable

I have a layout with a ImageView, which has no activity:

pieza.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/arribin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and on the other hand, I have a class in which I try to modify the layout to inflate:

```
public void init(){
    res = this.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources();
    lInf = (LayoutInflater)(getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    lInf.inflate(R.layout.game, this, true);
}

private int getPieceId(){
    //trying to set the image
   ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fast);
   return R.layout.pieza;
}
...
View newPiece = lInf.inflate(getPieceId(), null);
```

And LogCat:

ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on null object reference

Can I set the ImageView of a layout from a class without an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your above code is that the `image` ImageView is `null`. You should modify your `init()` method to be

```
View view = lInf.inflate(R.layout.game, this, true);
```

and then find the `ImageView` as follows:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

**EDIT**
Ok, so now that you mention it, I think your `pieza.xml` contains the `image` ImageView.
Modify your code as follows and check

```
View newPiece = lInf.inflate(R.layout.pieza, null);
ImageView image = (ImageView) newPiece.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fast);
```

You can comment the `getPieceId()` method. You don't need it.

Comment: I think these isn't the problem (just tried it and it didn't work). R.layout.game is the layout of the activity, and works ok. I think that the problem is pieza.xml hasn't activity. Thank you anyway

Comment: The logcat returns the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Every layout resource file should have a layout type.
It seems that pieza.xml does not have any Specific layout type (RelativeLayout,LinearLayout,...etc).

So, when you inflate the pieza.xml it will result in null.

Try using a LayoutType in pieza.xml at the beggining as a parent of ImageView and it should probabaly work.
Hope it helps...

**EDIT:**

It seems u are using R.layout.game to inflate the view....

Try inserting the ImageView in pieza.xml to game.xml...it wont show nullpointerException...

The reason is that findViewById() works to find references to the current set layout only i.e u cant only reference views that are child of inflated layout i think.